# Size Diff : Copy command doesn't copy all contents

Tags: linux, shell

I ran below command with root to take backup of a folder on the same host :
cp -r master master-backup

```
size of master : 76GB
size of master-backup : 71GB
```

any idea why am i getting size diff ?

Comment: different cluster size

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a matter of directory sizes. Directory is (at some level of thinking) just a file that contains some filenames along other metadata. If a directory keeps getting additions and removals, then it can grow much bigger over time. The `master-backup` has all the directories freshly created, so they are rather smallish.

Verify the file contents with `diff -r master master-backup`

Check the largest directory sizes with:

```
find master -type d -size +200 -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn | head
# repeat for master-backup
```

Other than that, the `cp -r` doesn't preserve the size in cases where you use some unusual stuff. For example: sparse files, security context, `xattr` entries.